# Prevent Azure Cloud Service from uninstalling software automatically

Tags: azure

We are running an Azure cloud service. We have an instance of Scalyr agent installed on the box to capture the logs. Every few days/weeks, the scalyr agent gets automatically removed from the instances. We believe this happens when windows automatically patches the boxes. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Which type of cloud service? What do you mean exactly by "box"?

Comment: Yes, we need to know what service you are using. If it's plain VM's then this should not be happening, if your using actual legacy cloud services, scale sets etc. then this may be by design

Comment: as @SamCogan said, this is the 'legacy' cloud service. The box is the instance that is launched by the cloud service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Services are the old, legacy solution , I would recommend you move away from that.

The issue you are having is due to you using cloud services, this is a PaaS solution where whatever you want to run on the VM is supposed to be part of your application bundle you deploy with the cloud service. Manually installing things on the cloud service VM's is not supported and you will see the issue you have observed.

You can see this from the docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me#monitoring):

> Unlike VMs created with Virtual Machines, writes made to Azure Cloud
> Services VMs aren't persistent. There's nothing like a Virtual
> Machines data disk

If you want a VM you can manually updated then you want to look at using IaaS virtual machines (and use the ARM version, not classic).

Comment: Thanks. It is true that MS is no longer developing Azure cloud services but they are not being deprecated AFAIK. It will require significant development effort to move away from Azure cloud services and this is not an option at the moment. Are you aware of any document which states that software can't be installed independently on the instances of the Azure cloud services?

Comment: You are correct, I had missed the exclusion for cloud services, however I would bet that we will see them retired eventually. I have updated the answer with details from the docs.

Comment: Many thanks. This clarifies the mystery :)